# Websocket timing out too soon

Tags: javascript, sockets, websocket, elixir, phoenix-framework

I've set up a standard Phoenix websocket/channel environment but I am not using the socket.js provided - I have my own (very simple) code that connects to the channels and topics. However, I can't get the socket to persist beyond a minute or so. Is there any way to define the timeout for sockets? I don't have any special configurations in the Phoenix-side (all standard as per the documentation)

My javascript code is as follows:

```
const ws = new WebSocket(sock_url);
ws.onmessage = (msg) => {
  const { payload, event } = JSON.parse(msg.data);
  if (!event.startsWith("phx_")) {
    onMessage(payload.body);
  }
};
ws.onclose = (code, reason) => {
  onClose(code, reason);
};
ws.onopen = () => {
  ws.send(JSON.stringify({
    topic: `users_socket:${user_id}`,
    event: "phx_join",
    payload: {},
    ref: '1'
  }));
};
```

**Update**: I ended up using the socket.js file that comes with Phoenix as everyone suggested - it just does everything I need. Thanks to everyone who answered :)

Comment: Is there any reason you are not just using the provided phoenix socket module?

Comment: It's part of a larger library and the request was to keep the code as simple and free from 'outside' libraries. But if I end up with too many issues of this type I may end up using the JS code that comes with phoenix.

Answer (score 3):

I am developing a project with Websockets (using Go not Phoenix or Elixir) and I've had the same disconnection problems that I've manage to solve (at least it has not been timing out since) by "pinging" the websocket i.e. sending a message in specific intervals.

Perhaps you could have something like this in your Javascript.

```
ws.onopen = () => {
  ws.send(/** YOUR CODE */);

  // Send a ping event every 10 seconds
  setInterval(() => ws.send(JSON.stringify({ event: "ping" })), 10000);
}
```

And handle this new event type accordingly server-side. Also you can try to monitor the `onclose` event and depending on the reason re-open the connection. You can find a list of such event codes in the [Mozilla docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CloseEvent).

Comment: Thanks! I was thinking of a similar solution, but was wondering if there was something built-in to the Phoenix socket implementation. I will mark this as the answer if there isn't.

Comment: Phoenix does exactly that https://github.com/phoenixframework/phoenix/blob/v1.2/web/static/js/phoenix.js#L546 I would recommend sticking with the standard implementation, it handles many more things such as fallback for browsers not supporting websockets, automatic reconnects when there are connection problems, local buffering of messages when client is offline, handling of presence info and more. Still it's just around 500 LOC (counted with `cloc`). Also, you won't benefit from bugfixes and updates to the official client. Highly recommend sticking with the standard solution.

Comment: @PatrickOscity Thanks Patrick. I never worked with Phoenix or Elixir so I didn't know the details of the framework. Just gave a generic solution. I agree that OP should use the framework's features if possible.

Comment: It's worth checking in `network` tab how Phoenix knocks into the channel to keep the socket's connection awake.

Answer (score 1):

phoenix backend expects a ping every 30 seconds. You can re-configure it like so:

```
defmodule UserSocket do
  use Phoenix.Socket

  ## Transports
  transport :websocket, Phoenix.Transports.WebSocket,
    timeout: 300_000, # 5 minutes
    transport_log: :debug
  ...

end
```

If you do not care for the timeout you can set it to very high. the code above sets it to 5 minutes.

In general phoenix.js will implement all of this for you. It is a very small lib. You will find at the end you implemented all that is in the lib with a bunch of things you got wrong :-)